# Failed to open Cloud Shell when using Concierge subscription/sandbox from Azure training

Tags: azure, shell, cloud, sandbox

1. I clicked "Activate Sandbox" button from an Azure training course page, signed in with my free Azure account and successfully activated my sandbox
2. I signed in to Azure portal and could see I was using the sandbox directory with concierge subscription
3. I clicked on the cloud shell icon to launch cloud shell, got "You have no storage mounted" page, clicked on "Create storage" button then got "Storage creation failed Error:403"
4. I went to my "Storage Accounts" page and saw a storage account associated with the sandbox was there
5. The strange thing is I was able to launch cloud shell following the same steps above for a few days, then it stopped working!
6. I followed troubleshooting tips in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting, cleared browser cache/cookies, used incognito window, nothing resolved the issue
7. I tried the same steps, in office, at home with vpn, at home without vpn, nothing resolved the issue
8. I don't want to create pay-as-you-go account and incur charges just for doing online training

Any resolution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, still no solution it seems